# Do - while loop with conditions using Char (Java)

Tags: java, do-while

So I'm working on this energy tree project for my computer programming class, I was trying to make a do-while loop that asked the user if they were a producer or consumer and if any other input was entered loop would start over. My code keeps getting the error

```
"java.util.NoSuchElementException" on line 45
```

where it says

```
char Type = ProducerOrConsumer.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
```

```java
        boolean isChoiceValid = false;

        do
        {
            PETCScanner.close();
            Scanner ProducerOrConsumer = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Are you a Producer or a Consumer?\\\\n (P = Producer, C = Consumer");
            char Type = ProducerOrConsumer.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            if (Type == 'P' || Type =='C')
            {


            }
            else 
                System.out.println("Sorry try Again");
            {

            }
            String Name = ProducerOrConsumer.nextLine().toUpperCase();

            System.out.println(Name);


        }while(isChoiceValid == (true));
        System.out.println("You're Done!");


    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `{}` outside the else?

Comment: Is there any way you can post code that will compile without change, and that will reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are closing a Scanner, which *closes all attached resources*. When trying to read again, you have "no such element" to read.

You only need one scanner per application, there is no need to re-create one, too.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean isChoiceValid = false;
do {
     System.out.println("Are you a Producer or a Consumer?\\\\n (P = Producer, C = Consumer");
    char type = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    if (type == 'P' || type =='C') {
        boolean isChoiceValid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry try Again");
        isValidChoice = false;  // if you want
        continue;
    }
    if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
} while(!isChoiceValid);
System.out.println("You're Done!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the exception was thrown from the calling `ProducerOrConsumer.nextLine()`.

There was no element found as the `result == null`. You can have a look more detailed in the `java.util.Scanner.nextLine()`

```
public String nextLine() {
        ...
        if (result == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found");
        ...
        if (result == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        ...
}
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

After removing `PETCScanner.close();` I ran your code, and I don't get any errors. I get this:

```
Are you a Producer or a Consumer?\\n (P = Producer, C = Consumer
Neither
Sorry try Again
O
O
You're Done!
```

Comment: Well, `PETCScanner` is never defined in the question, so how did you compile it?

Comment: I added `import java.util.Scanner;` and  `public class testing7 {` and `public static void main(String[] args) {` I then commented out `// PETCScanner.close();` Added a `}` as the end (closing the class). Then I used `javac` .. really quite simple.

Comment: We're just trying to understand... Read the code, think about it... It's  a while loop. The variable is never changed. Why does the loop stop?

Comment: There are two kinds of while loops. One is `while (condition) {doSomething}` here the condition is checked in the beginning and the doSomething will only be done if the condition is true. The other is a `do {dosomethingelse} while (condition)`. This will always run at least once, because the condition is checked at the end of every run. Since isChoiceValid is false, the statement runs once and exists. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: :) I get it now. Apologies